# Javascript array explication

Tags: javascript

Given this two arrays **a** and **b**:

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = a;
a.push(4);

console.log(b); /* [1,2,3,4]  */
console.log(a); /* [1,2,3,4]  */
```

Why isn't **b** equal with [1,2,3] ?

Comment: `b` holds the reference to array `a`

Comment: JS object do not copy. They just pass reference

Comment: @thefourtheye https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript?

Comment: @Bergi Sure. I reopened it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `b` holds the reference to array `a`. You need to copy the array instead use **[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** method to copy.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = a.slice();
a.push(4);

console.log(b);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: so, in order to be equal to [1,2,3] (initial value of array a), I assume I have to clone it right ?

Comment: @webenergized :  yes you need to. In case the elements are objects then you need to clone in deeper

Comment: Thank you for the info sir, I will accept your answer in ~10 mins